relation between first and second solution of Kummer equation (confluent hypergeometric functions of first and second kind)
As stated in DLMF 13.2, the solutions to the differential equation
$$z\frac{d^2w}{dz^2}+(b-z)\frac{dw}{dz}-aw=0$$
are the Kummer function of the first kind $M(a,b,z)$ and second kind $U(a,b,z)$. If $b\notin \mathbb{Z}$ then one can say
$$U(a,b,z) = \frac{\Gamma(1-b)}{\Gamma(a-b+1)}M(a,b,z)+z^{1-b}\frac{\Gamma(b-1)}{\Gamma(a)}M(a-b+1,2-b,z)$$
Also using the identity $\Gamma(1-x)\Gamma(x) = \pi \csc(\pi x)$ we can deduce
$$U(a,b,z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi b)}\left[\frac{M(a,b,z)}{\Gamma(a-b+1)\Gamma(b)}-z^{1-b}\frac{M(a-b+1,2-b,z)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(2-b)}\right]$$
I have two questions.
1- Which one of the above equations can be used in the limit when $b\to m, n\in \mathbb{Z}$ to evaluate the value of function if we assume the function is defined such that it is continuous? In "Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables" by Abramowitz and Stegun it is asserted that only the second definition is valid but in DLMF 13.2 the second equation is not even mentioned, why though? As much as I can tell they are equivalent.
2- I tried to evaluate both equations numerically to see which one gives me the value of $U(a,b,z)$ using $M(a,b,z)$ however non of the above equations returns the correct value that $U(a,b,z)$ returns! I used MATLAB environment where $M(a,b,z)$ is the built-in function $hypergeom(a,b,z)$ and the $U(a,b,z)$ is the built-in function $kummerU(a,b,z)$. I am confident that both $hypergeom(a,b,z)$ and $kummerU(a,b,z)$ are implemented correctly by Mathworks (I cross-validated different values with Mathematica) What is happening here?
I am only concerned with the real line and all the values and parameter are also real numbers.
Thank you in advance

If I remember, the second solution is a generalized Laguerre polynomial $L_{-a}^{b-1}(z)$
